# Visual Studio 2008 C ++ stopping during Linking

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, linker

I have written some image processing program using OpenCV 2.1
I received a error during linking, related to "projectname.ilk" file.(message said VS is trying a non-incremental linking). So I triied rebuilding the project. The initial message went away, but now VS never completes "Linking". 
It prints "1>Linking..." and stays that way.

What might be the problem?

Thanks

Comment: Try a clean build. Also, if you hit an error look it up on MSDN or post about it here.

Comment: no errors nothin.. just prints Linking... and waits

Answer (score 2):

If clean build fails to remedy, try eliminating /LTCG on the link and whole program optimization in c++. There have been some defects in this area.